# Tips for creating a realistic procedural dirt/ground texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I've been messing around with ground textures, dirt, specifically, and I'm not really getting anything super realistic. Basically, I'm just combining a bunch of noise textures with a MixRGB set to difference. I've got it looking alright (see picture) [image]. Does anyone have tips for how to improve this texture?

Comment: There are many knind of dirt/ground texture. Could you show a reference image of what you are looking for and highlite the relevant features? Are you using cycles render engine?

Comment: [example of what I'm looking for.](http://senderomaterials.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/OrganicTopSoil.jpg) Oh and I am using cycles.